# SQL Server Replication Add Check Constraint in Publisher Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints, database-replication, merge-replication

I'm new to replication and would like to know the impact of creating a check constraint on a publisher table both in case of merge replication and transaction repl.

Both the cases, repl is already setup, would the replication break if I set up the check the constraint or would I need to re-initialize the subs after creating the check constraint.

Please let know what are precautionary steps I need to take

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT xx CHECK ()
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [xx]
 GO
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use code blocks in your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The replication will not break because of this change.  I normally don't work with merge replication but confirmed adding a check constraint does not break merge replication either.  You might consider using the NOT FOR REPLICATION command line if you don't want the constraint replicated and enforced on the subscriber.  I like to control this at the publisher level.

Answer (score 0):

For existing publications you can view the properties to see if CHECK CONSTRAINTS are published to the subscriber.

Right Click - Properties - Articles - Set Properties of Highlighted Article.

If it's false, you don't need to worry about it being pushed to the subscriber.

[Properties viewed using SSMS on Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwlLi.png)